# Volley Image - Load From Resource

Tags: android, android-volley, android-studio-2.2

Is it possible to use VOLLEY to load images from the drawable folder? U use the to load from the web, but in some cases i would like to load from drawable:

```
// Load image
ImageRequest ImageRequest = new ImageRequest(events_image_01,
        new Response.Listener<Bitmap>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Bitmap response) {
                background.setImageBitmap(response);
            }
        }, 0, 0, ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY, null, new Response.ErrorListener(){
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Sorry! Error Loading Image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        error.printStackTrace();
    }
});
MySingleton.getmInstance(getActivity()).addToRequestQueue(ImageRequest);
```

Comment: why not just- background.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.yourDrawable))

Comment: Because even after loading a couple of small images i run out of cache. Especially on older android versions. tried picasso before, but so far i like volley more.

Comment: Volley is network library you can ofcourse  extend ImageRequest and make custom ImageRequest that does not do web work but returns the bitmap, but i dont see how this would be better than just setting the imageDrawable

Answer (score 0):

Volley is not really designed for image loading, but it can do it. What you really want is one of these two libraries, which both have very simple syntax and handle almost everything for you (download, resize, caching):

Glide
https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Picasso
http://square.github.io/picasso/

Generally the perception is that Glide is better for most instances (Picasso can do Widgets out of the box), and it's my go-to for most applications. There are other options out there (Fresco, if you want lots of control), but these are the two easiest to just drop in.

For your use case you could do:

Drawable:
Glide.with(context).load(R.drawable.my_image_resouce).into(imageView);

Url:
Glide.with(context).load(myUrl).into(imageView);